# Is there a way to create an desktop application with that office2007 toolbar for free?

Tags: c#, .net, ribbon

I found several controlsets for that nice looking ribbons (DotNetBar, DivElements, ...), but all require a license for at least 100 USD. Is there a free controlset that looks quite as nice as the commericial ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can download the Microsoft WPF Ribbon Control through the Office Developer UI Licence.

It was meant to be released last week.

http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx

I'll see if i can dig out a download link.

Edit:

Think this is what your looking for
[Office Fluent User Interface Developer Portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905530.aspx)

Comment: The link is broken (use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905530.aspx ) but the answer will fit best to my needs - thanks

Answer (score 3):

Might want to take a look at http://arstechnica.com/journals/linux.ars/2007/08/30/mono-developer-brings-the-ribbon-interface-to-linux

It's for mono, but might be worth a look.

Comment: I love open source and am fascinated by the mono project, but I am yet not ready to use GTK for this. ;-) Maybe some day.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one on codeproject:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/WinFormsRibbon.aspx